# LINQ GroupBy collection

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Is it possible to GroupBy in LINQ, using a collection property?

e.g.

```
void Main()
{
    var t1 = new Test() { Children = new List<string>() { "one", "two" } };
    var t2 = new Test() { Children = new List<string>() { "one", "two" } };
    var t3 = new Test() { Children = new List<string>() { "one", "three" }        };

    var tests = new List<Test>() { t1, t2, t3 };
    var anon =  from t in tests
                select new
                {
                    Children = t.Children
                };

    anon.GroupBy(t => t.Children).Dump();
}

public class Test
{
    public List<string> Children {get;set;}
}
```

In this example, I would hope for two groups:

> Key: List() { "one", "two" } Value: t1, t2
>
> Key: List() { "one", "three" } Value: t3

My understanding is that anonymous types are compared not by reference, but by comparing equality on their public properties.

However, the actual result is three groups:

> Key: List() { "one", "two" } Value: t1
>
> Key: List() { "one", "two" } Value: t2
>
> Key: List() { "one", "three" } Value: t3

If this is not possible, is there a way to get the result I want?

Hopefully explained this clearly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the lists are not exactly identical. It's comparing equality for grouping, and you have two new `List<string>`s, which aren't exactly equal. You can, however, join the strings by hash code, which would produce a correct result:

```
tests.GroupBy(t => String.Join(string.Empty, t.Children.Select(c => c.GetHashCode().ToString())));
```

Comment: Thanks - I do understand that (my code sample was simplified from my real problem). Please see my modified code sample

Comment: I have updated my answer to work with your existing code. Please take a look at it. It also doesn't require a custom `IEqualityComparer`.

Comment: This generates very weird results if the hashcode happens to be the same.

Answer (score 4):

By default, `GroupBy` is going to use reference equality when grouping by lists (which are reference types).

Since you've got new instances of the list each time, they are not equal.

However, there is an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334.aspx) of `GroupBy` which lets you specify a custom [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx), so that you can implement your own way of comparing a list of strings, for example.

To implement this, there are many [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546925/comparing-two-liststring-for-equality) here about comparing two lists.

Comment: Thanks - I do understand that (my code sample was simplified from my real problem). Please see my modified code sample

Comment: My answer still applies, you need to create a custom `IEqualityComparer` that compares the equality of each member in two lists of strings. Then, pass that as the second parameter to `GroupBy`.

Comment: Would you consider a custom IEqualityComparer a little too much for a one-off LINQ grouping that probably will not be needed twice?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get 3 groups is because `List<T>` implements equality with default reference-equality, not by considering the "sequence equality" of the contained elements between any two lists. If you want such semantics, you'll have to implement an `IEqualityComparer<IList<T>>` (or similar) yourself and inject that into the `GroupBy` query using the overload that accepts an equality-comparer. Here's a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598368/compare-objects/4598406#4598406) implementation (for arrays, not lists, but easily adaptable).

If you're comfortable with *set* equality (order and duplicates are irrelevant), you're in luck: you can directly use `HashSet<T>` and the provided [`CreateSetComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335475.aspx) method for the comparer implementation:

```
  var t1 = new Test { Children = new HashSet<string> { "one", "two" } };
  var t2 = new Test { Children = new HashSet<string> { "one", "two" } };
  var t3 = new Test { Children = new HashSet<string> { "one", "three" } };

  var tests = new List<Test> { t1, t2, t3 };

  // Only two groups: { one, two } and { one, three }
  tests.GroupBy(t => t.Children, HashSet<string>.CreateSetComparer())
       .Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a built in method to that.

Look at Jon Skeet's answer here:

[Any chance to get unique records using Linq (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724479/any-chance-to-get-unique-records-using-linq-c)